# When is $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ a scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ be the moduli stack (over $\mathbb{Z}$) of smooth genus $g$ curves $X\rightarrow S$ with $n$ (ordered) sections.

Does the usual definition require the sections to be **disjoint** as closed subschemes of $X$?

I remember hearing somewhere that for any $g$, there exists an integer $n_g$ such that for all $n\ge n_g$, $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ is a scheme.

My question is - what are these integers $n_g$?

Does the answer change if we consider moduli stacks of stable marked curves $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$ instead?

Comment: Yes, the sections must be disjoint. $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ is a scheme when any automorphism of a curve of genus $g$ fixing $n$ points is the identity; this happens for instance when $n>2g+2$, by the Hurwitz formula. And this works also for $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$, by considering the normalization.

Comment: Two relevant facts: if a quasi-separated Artin stack has trivial Aut-schemes at its geometric points then it is an algebraic space (see Theorem 2.2.5(1) of http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/kmpaper.pdf), and if an algebraic space is quasi-finite and separated over a scheme then it is a scheme.  So when $n>2g+2$ (to ensure that the unramified Aut-scheme is trivial at geometric points) then one "just" has to find a quasi-finite map from the (separated) algebraic space $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ to a separated scheme.

Comment: @nfdc23 Is it "easy" to find a quasi-finite map to a separated scheme? I don't see how one might do that for $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$

Comment: Your question about making such a quasi-finite map is very apt, and is related to why I am amazed that this has been called a "duplicate" question -- cheap tricks (like the $j$-map to $\mathbf{P}^1$) don't help when $g>1$.  The case $g>1$ is much deeper than the case $g=1$ for this essential issue. The "duplicate" label is a serious mistake for exactly that reason. This thread is invisible to the world because the genus-1 "duplicate" has replaced the above question. If the question can be restored to its rightful place (with "duplicate" removed) then I'll think more about the quasi-finite map.

Comment: Here is a proof that the algebraic space $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ (say $n>2g+2$) is a scheme. It suffices to work over $\mathbf{Z}[1/\ell]$ for two primes $\ell>2$. Invert $\ell>2$ and make the finite etale ${\rm{GL}}_{2g}(\mathbf{Z}/(\ell))$-torsor $M_{g,n,\ell}\rightarrow \mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ classifying full level-$\ell$ structures on the relative Jacobian. It suffices to exhibit the algebraic space $M_{g,n,\ell}$ as  a quasi-projective scheme, as then its quotient $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ by the free action of the finite group ${\rm{GL}}_{2g}(\mathbf{Z}/(\ell))$ is a quasi-projective scheme.[cont'd]

Comment: WLOG $g>1$ ($g=0, 1$ are "easy"), so by Mumford's GIT the functor classifying smooth proper curves with geometric fibers connected of genus $g$ and equipped with full level-$\ell$ structure on the relative Jacobian is represented by a quasi-projective $\mathbf{Z}[1/\ell]$-scheme $M_{g,\ell}$.  The stack $\mathcal{M}_{g,m,\ell}$ over $\mathbf{Z}[1/\ell]$ is an algebraic space for any $m\ge 0$ and is $M_{g,\ell}$ for $m=0$. Thus, it suffices to show for any $m\ge 0$ that $M_{g,m+1,\ell}$ is open in the universal curve over $M_{g,m,\ell}$ (whose relative $\Omega^1$ is relatively ample!).[cont'd]

Comment: Knudsen used "contraction" and "stabilization" constructions to identify  $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,m+1}$ as the universal curve over $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,m}$ when $2g-2+m>0$. This involves "forgetting" the last marked section and then performing some operations if that yields an $m$-marked curve which is not stable. But since $g>1$, away from the boundary no such operation arises! Hence, the stack $\mathcal{M}_{g,m+1}$ is open in $\mathcal{M}_{g,m}$, so $M_{g,m+1,\ell}$ is thereby open inside the universal curve over $M_{g,m,\ell}$. QED! This proof avoided the "quasi-finite map" idea.

Comment: I believe nfdc explained why it should be reopened in the comments, and I agree.